# error en ejecucion de la clase main

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas mi problema es que al querer ejecutar una clase desde el main tengo problemas para imprimir y ejecutarla

```
class Persona(object):
#Definimos un constructor que recibe nombre y edad
def __init__(self,nombre,edad):
    self.nombre=nombre
    self.edad=edad



class Alumno(Persona):
#Hereda de la clase persona , el parametro de asignaturas se recibe como arbitrarios

#cuantas asignaturas tendra el alumno
 def __init__(self,nombre,edad, *arbitrarios):
    #VALIDAMOS LA EDAD PARA VER SI ES NUMERICO
    if isinstance(edad, int()):
        Persona.__init__(self, nombre, edad)
        self.asignaturas=[] #Creamos una lista vacia de asginaturas
        for parametro in arbitrarios:
            self.asignaturas.append(parametro)

        self.finalizados=False #Lo inicializamos en falso 
    else:
        raise TypeError ("El valor de la edad debe ser numerico")


def finaliza(self):
    if (self.finalizados == False):
        self.finalizados = True

    else:
        print("ya ha finalizado sus estudios")

def asignatura(self,a):
    self.asignaturas.append(a)

def __str__(self):
    asignaturas=""
    for i in self.asignaturas:
        asignaturas = asignaturas,",",i

    return "El alumno",self.nombre,"tiene las siguientes asignaturas:",asignaturas
```

El MAIN

```
from Clases.Ejercicio1 import *

alumno=Alumno('Juan GARCIA PEREZ',23,'PSP','SISTEMAS DE GESTION')
print(alumno)
alumno.finaliza()
alumno.asignatura('Ingles')
print(alumno)
```

El error que me lanza este

> ```
> if isinstance(edad, int()):
>   TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que isinstance recibe como parámetro un argumento no válido, por eso te devuelve el error:

> ```
> if isinstance(edad, int()):
>   TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
> ```

Realizando de la siguiente manera se soluciona el problema:

```
if isinstance(edad, int):
```

Otro problema es que la función `__str__` está devolviendo un valor que no es string, lo cual está lanzando otro error

> ```
> TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
> ```

aplicando la siguiente corrección funciona a la perfección.

```
 def __str__(self):
    asignaturas=""
    for asignatura in self.asignaturas:
        asignaturas += '%s, '%str(asignatura)

    return asignaturas
```

Comment: muchas gracias podrias explicarme esta linea , no la suelo usar `asignaturas += '%s, '%str(asignatura)`

Comment: Es un formato de string, en este caso se reemplaza el %s por la variable asignatura, podes ver la documentación y más caso de uso [aquí](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html "Strings")